# Python parser. Need to read the "Name and author" out of a text file and out put all of the collected names into another text file

Tags: python, parsing, text

I'm trying to take two things out of text files that are in folders and output them into a neat list in a single text file. I've never done something like this before and all of the online resources are either too simple for my task or too complex for my task.I have a feeling this task is specific to what I'm trying to do.

```
[Info]
name         = "bridget"
displayname  = "BRIDGET"
versiondate  = 04,13,2002
mugenversion = 04,14,2001
author       = "[fraya]"
pal.defaults = 1
```

All I'm trying to do is take the "displayname" and "author" text fields and output them to a file in a list with the format "(displayname) by (author)"

a parser was the first thing that came to my mind when I wanted to try this (and python I heard was a good choice for this).
So if anyone could point me in the right direction or give me some building blocks that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write a parser; this is (almost) standard .ini file format, which can be read by the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module. You'll just need to strip the quotes when you output the values.

To get you started:

```
import configparser
c = configparser.ConfigParser()
c.read(['myfilename.ini'])
info = c['Info']
displayname = info['displayname'].strip('"')
author = info['author'].strip('"')
print("{} by {}".format(displayname, author))
```

Comment: I'll give this a look. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!